# PHP: store a global information so it can be accessed by all other users?

Tags: php, global-variables, session-cookies, php-5.4

Is there a way that PHP can track and keep a data for what page is being accessed and then this piece of data can be opened/ accessed by all other computers/ users?

For instance, when I am inside my CMS and editing a page called 'home' then I want to store this data in a global (maybe??) so the front end users can know that this page is being edited.

I was thinking using `$_SESSION` in the backend,

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $_REQUEST['url'];
```

Then in the front end page that is being viewed by other person from another machines,

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

and this could be the result,

```
Array
(
    [url] => home
)
```

Of course it does not work! Any ideas what I can do to store a global information so it can be accessed by all other computers/ users?

Comment: Database, File, Serialized Object...? Or did I miss something?

Comment: `$_SESSION` is only used for storing data for the CURRENT user, so not ALL users.

Comment: Your concept seem to be wrong anyway ... "let users know that this page is being edited" ... ok nice to inform them - better, to not let them access such a page. So you need a database ("lock"), which holds all files currently being edited ... So I start editing a page - and then don't submit it for hours ... hmmm ;)

Comment: just thought of using a table in the database after submitting this question! thank you! :)

Comment: @wumm please consider posting your comment as an answer so the question can be closed.